# Azure functions V3 logging exceptions in startup file

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-functions, error-logging

Currently we are preapring a set of `azure functions` to trigger a `blob storage`. The function app V3 should do some kind of checks on startup. So I added the `Startup.cs` file in the VS solution. The problem what I'm having is that sometimes exceptions happen while performing these checks in the startup  file. But I never find these exceptions in azure portal `(application insights/exceptions)`. I tried many ways to implement logging there, but unfortunately the app keeps saying `Host is not running` without any logging in these logs:

[image]

I'm not talking about the logs of a specific function, I mean here the logs of the function app on startup.

This is the code where it throws the exception in `startup.cs`:

```
try
{
   // async method CheckSomeBlobsFiles
   CheckSomeBlobsFiles(connectionString, 
       blobContainerName, blobDirectoryName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   throw new Exception($"Error while checking database schemas: {e.Message}");
}
```

Comment: is it working locally? and why do you need a startup.cs ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, yes but even if not, I can locally debug and check what are the problems and fix them. It is not about if working or not, it is about, how can i catch the exceptions happening in the startup file

Comment: @Sajeetharan, i already mentioned that i want a startup because I run a db migration there. Method: CheckSomeBlobsFiles

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-a-service-that-depends-on-ilogger

Comment: @alaa_sayegh, can you try directly write this error to application insights, then throw it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, for the exceptions from `Startup.cs`, you can find it in azure portal -> **Diagnose and solve problems** blade.

The steps as beow:

1.Nav to azure portal -> your function app -> on the left side, click on **Diagnose and solve problems** -> then input **function app down** in the search box -> then click on the **Function App Down or Reporting Errors**. The screenshot as below:

[image]

2.In the new page of **Function App Down or Reporting Errors**, expand
**Function Executions and Errors** -> then expand **Detected host offline in your function app**. Then you can see the exceptions in the startup.cs are logged there(if it's not there, please specify a proper time range on this page). The screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! These cryptic ways to get error details are really annoying sometimes ><

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with [`HttpRequestException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpexception?view=netframework-4.8) as shown the following code?

```
 catch (HttpRequestException ex)
 {
    throw new Exception($"Error while checking database schemas: {e.Message}");
 }
```

Comment: thanks, but can you pls elaborate on why should this work?

Comment: I am not sure if this would work, but this way to get exceptions thrown by the HttpClient as you are making an Http request

Comment: Interesting then i guess problem with the actual trigger itself. Why dont you check if the function is getting invoked?